# How can I replace "<br>" with "</div><div>"?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, replace

I get an imported text block, but the formatting is not always so perfect. I try to fix this with jquery afterwards. So I started to replace `<br>` with `<div></div>`:

```js
$('.details').html().replace(/<br>\\*/g,"</div><div>");

if ($('.details div').is(':empty')) { 
    $(this).remove();
}
```

```css
.details div {
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #777;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 4px 0;
    margin: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0, .05);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="details">
monkey<br>
elephant<br>
rabbit<br>
sun<br>
moon<br><div>
bird
<br></div><div><br></div><div>gras</div><div></div><span>
house<br>
way<br>
silience<br></span><div>
love
<br></div><div><br></div><div>somewhere
<br></div><div><br></div><div><span>land</span></div><div></div><div><span>
kanguroo</span> <br></div><div><br></div><div>tv</div>                                                         
                                                            </div>
```

But the replace is not working.
The final html should look like this:

```
<div class="details">
    <div>monkey</div>   
    <div>elephant</div> 
    <div>rabbit</div>   
    <div>sun</div>  
    <div>moon</div> 
    <div>bird</div> 
    <div>gras</div>
    <div>house</div>    
    <div>way</div>  
    <div>silience</div> 
    <div>love</div> 
    <div>somewhere</div>    
    <div>land</div>
    <div>kanguroo</div> 
    <div>tv</div>                                                          
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the DOM with your replacement!

Just change

```
$('.details').html().replace(/<br>\\*/g,"</div><div>");
```

to

```
$('.details').html($('.details').html().replace(/<br>\\*/g,"</div><div>"));
```

```js
$('.details').html($('.details').html().replace(/<br>\\*/g,"</div><div>"));

$('.details div:empty').remove();
```

```css
.details div {
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #777;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 4px 0;
    margin: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0, .05);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="details">
monkey<br>
elephant<br>
rabbit<br>
sun<br>
moon<br><div>
bird
<br></div><div><br></div><div>gras</div><div></div><span>
house<br>
way<br>
silience<br></span><div>
love
<br></div><div><br></div><div>somewhere
<br></div><div><br></div><div><span>land</span></div><div></div><div><span>
kanguroo</span> <br></div><div><br></div><div>tv</div>                                                         
                                                            </div>
```

Comment: One question, the removement of the empty div, is it the same reason with the DOM, why it is not working?

Comment: not the same! what does the `this` refer to in `$(this).remove();`?

Comment: "this" refers to ".details div" (if it is empty)

Comment: Now all divs are removed, I probably need a foreach

Comment: Meant `$('.details div:empty').remove();`

Comment: *`this` refers to ".details div"* - it very likely does not.   Without context (event handler), `this === window`.   Make sure you always know what `this` is when using it.